# How to fix this error ? Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I have 3 XML layouts united with 1 activity with ViewPager and that contain gif assets that I retrieve from firebase storage. When trying to retrieve 2 image assets this code works. But when I retrieve another 1 image asset, this code has an error, and the application force closes.
I can make sure that there is nothing wrong with my 3rd XML layouts.

See my onCreate function below :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice)

    val gifImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("gif/step1.gif")
    val gifImage2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("gif/step2_left.gif")
    val gifImage2Right = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("gif/step2_right.gif")
    val localFile = File.createTempFile("tempGif", "gif")
    val localFile2 = File.createTempFile("tempGif2", "gif")
    val localFile2Right = File.createTempFile("tempGif2Right", "gif")

    gifImage.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val gifFromPath = GifDrawable(localFile.absolutePath)
        img.setImageDrawable(gifFromPath)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    gifImage2.getFile(localFile2).addOnSuccessListener {
        val gif2FromPath = GifDrawable(localFile2.absolutePath)
        img2.setImageDrawable(gif2FromPath)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    gifImage2Right.getFile(localFile2Right).addOnSuccessListener {
        val gif2RightFromPath = GifDrawable(localFile2Right.absolutePath)
        img2Right.setImageDrawable(gif2RightFromPath)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    init()
    dataSet()
    interaction()
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I add the code below, I get an error :

```
gifImage2Right.getFile(localFile2Right).addOnSuccessListener {
        val gif2RightFromPath = GifDrawable(localFile2Right.absolutePath)
        img2Right.setImageDrawable(gif2RightFromPath)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Screenshot of the error :
[image: Error Screenshot]

What's wrong with my code? all the help I am very grateful.

Comment: One of the ImageView objects you are using is null. Try to initialize it before actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurs due below reasons:

1- view which you are trying to access its not available in the layout file which is set on the activity or fragment.

2- view is present in the layout which is set on the activity or fragment but you are accessing it before initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

1: In your case seems like view is not present to your current scope.

Get your image view `img2` like this in code

```
img2 = findViewById(R.id.id_to_your_xml_imagView);
```

before setting drawable image to it.